# Load json data in service and return it to component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, http-get

I have a component with it's controller and template. I'm using a service to load data from a `json` file and return it to my component. The returned data should be looped within the template of the component. At the moment, the `console.log()` in my service shows me the correct data, so it loads everything from the `json` file. The `console.log()` in my component is wrong. I know, there are few questions with answers, but they didn't help me. Is there a problem with asynchron loading? Any ideas? I also attached the console errors on the bottom of the question.

**test.json**

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Item 1"
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Item 2"
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "Name": "Item 3"
  }
]
```

**test.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { NavigationService } from "../../../services/navigation.service";

export type NavigationListModel = { Id: number; Name: string };

@Component({
  selector: "test",
  templateUrl: "./test.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./test.component.scss"]
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  navigationList: Array<NavigationListModel>;

  constructor(private _navService: NavigationService) {
    this.navigationList = this._navService.loadNavigationList();
    console.log(this.navigationList);
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**test.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class NavigationService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  loadNavigationList() {
    return this.http
      .get("/assets/mock/test/test.json")
      .map(data => data.json() as Array<NavigationService>)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        return data;
      });
  }
}
```

**test.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of navigationList">
  {{item.Name}}
</div>
```

**ERROR IN CONSOLE and CONSOLE.LOG() results:**

[image]

Comment: On a side note, you shouldn't do initialization in your components constructor. You will want to move that logic to the OnInit() life cycle hook.

Answer (score 0):

When you create service that has return towards HTTP and it is async, you need to subscribe to that function where you call it. As you can see your console log tells you that it is subscription.

Try :

```
this._navService.loadNavigationList().subscribe((data: any) => {
    console.log(data)
});
```

Or you can recreate your service that will return new Promise with resolve and error, I usually perfer to do it this way

```
 loadNavigationList() {
    return new Promise((error, resolve) => {
     this.http
      .get("/assets/mock/test/test.json")
      .map(data => data.json() as Array<NavigationService>)
      .subscribe((data) => {
        // if api, check for errr
        if(data.code == 500) {
          error(something);
          return
        }
        resolve(data)
      });
    });
  }
```

Where you will call it

```
loadNavigationList().then((data) => {

}, (err) => {

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through the navigationList field which is still undefined because of the asynchronous call (the response is not yet received).

To fix this problem you have to make your loadNavigationList() method return an observable of Array and use it in the test componennt with the async pipe inside the template:

test.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class NavigationService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  loadNavigationList() {
    return this.http
      .get("/assets/mock/test/test.json")
      .map(data => data.json() as Array<NavigationService>);
  }
}
```

test.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { NavigationService } from "../../../services/navigation.service";

export type NavigationListModel = { Id: number; Name: string };

@Component({
  selector: "test",
  templateUrl: "./test.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./test.component.scss"]
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  navigationListObservable$: Observable<Array<NavigationListModel>>;

  constructor(private _navService: NavigationService) {
    this.navigationList$ = this._navService.loadNavigationList();
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

test.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of  (navigationListObservable$ | async)">
      {{item.Name}}
</div>
```